# problem in building image file with docker

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, docker-image, docker-build

im trying to build a image file for first time on a very simple project as a test but when i run

> docker build -t test .

i get this error:

```
=> ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:alpine                                                                                            3.3s 
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:alpine:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: failed open: failed to do request: Get "https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/ad/adb3ed8bc61ee6fb46e5ece58f9821faf5fe5be4e1ef34e678b322639f17852a/data?verify=1681907974-z9H6vo8k0MeYfoN3xhTsynGtEWw%3D": x509: certificate is valid for denied.shecan.ir, not production.cloudflare.docker.com
```

i have 2files in directory:
1-app.js
2-Dockerfile

app.js contains:

```
console.log("this is the first try of docker ")
```

Dockerfile contains:

```
FROM node:alpine
COPY  . /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD node app.js
```

i tried disabling docker builder engine and running this command in powershell:

> & 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe' -SwitchDaemon

Comment: It looks like your ISP is hijacking the connection to cloudflare and redirecting it to a server called "denied.shecan.ir". Not something you can solve with programming, I'm afraid.

Comment: this the error after solving denied.shecan.ir :        => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:alpine                          16.7s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:alpine:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to authorize: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to fetch anonymous token: Get "https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fnode%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io": net/http: TLS handshake timeoutPS E:\project\app>

Comment: I'm afraid you did not "solve" anything. Your connection is timing out before the first TLS handshake occurs. That means you are still being blocked at the network level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was my IPv6 that was turned off,by turning it on the problem solved